# Configure Google webmaster console to ignore duplicate subdomain

Tags: domains, google-search-console, web-hosting, subdomain

I have a site hosted on x10hosting. This site is assigned to a free subdomain. `example.x10host.com`.

I have now purchased my own domain: `example.com`

Unfortunately, x10hosting does not seem to allow me to change the main domain from the free `.x10host.com` to my new .com domain.  Instead, I can either setup a parked domain - which redirects all traffic from `example.com` to `example.x10host.com`.

OR

It allows an add on domain. This is better in that if you go to `example.com` ... That is what is displayed as the web address in the browser.  If I use the parked domain option, it shows that it has redirected to my `example.x10host.com`.

Soooo.... My question is: What would be the best way to manage these 2 domains in relation to google and other search engines.  I'm guessing Google will find 2 domains with duplicate content. How can I ensure that only `example.com` is indexed and not `example.x10host.com`.

I have google webmaster console setup for both domains.  As they share the same content - they also share the `robots.txt` file - so not sure how I can permanently stop Google indexing the x10host subdomain.

Comment: What kind of webserver is it? Do you have access to (something like) .htaccess? What server-side scripting language are you using? PHP?

Comment: X10hosting uses cPanel. So I can access .htaccess from its file manager.

Comment: I did think of another idea... The add on domain does not have to point to the root html folder. It can point to a custom folder.  So I may be able to move my website into a custom folder... Point mywebsite.com domain to that folder, and then remove the html documents on the root (that x10host.com subdomain uses.  If this works - will it solve the duplicate content issue.  Or is there a better way.  I'm hopeful mywebsite.com will see its 'folder' as its 'root' so it can have its own robots.txt.

Comment: I could then have a robots.txt in the root folder that disallows all - making the subdomain redundant - while my website.com points to a folder that has its own robots.txt allowing it to be indexed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can access .htaccess from its file manager.

In which case the easiest/safest way is probably just to set up a permanent redirect from the subdomain to the main domain (assuming both the subdomain and main domain are pointing to the same place):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} x10host [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Where `example.com` is your canonical domain name.

Another approach is to set a `<link rel="canonical"` element in the `head` section of your pages pointing to the canonical URL. This will also avoid duplicate content issues with Google, providing both domains are verified in Google's Search Console. However, users would still be able to access your site by the x10host subdomain.

I'm not aware that you can specify this preference in Google Search Console alone, since you will still need to setup (and confirm) a 301 redirect.

> I can either setup a parked domain - which redirects all traffic from `example.com` to `example.x10host.com`.

"Parked domains" don't normally perform an external redirection? Although this is usually an additional option that can be set in cPanel. (Maybe x10hosting do something different in this respect?)

Comment: I will try this now.  Do I add my entire subdomain address where you have x10host? Eg example.x10host.com

Comment: No need to include the entire subdomain, the above (regular expression) will match if `x10host` occurs anywhere in the _host_. (Assuming that your actual domain doesn't contain the string "x10host"! :)

Comment: Cool. The .htaccess seems to work so far.  If I try and go to example.x10host.com it redirects to example.com. Since I have both domains in my Google webmaster console... I went to my x10host subdomain, selected change of address, and then selected my new domain to indicate I'm moving my site to a new domain.  It passed the 301 redirect and verification and has been submitted - so hopefully all indexing from my subdomain will be transferred to my new one... Not sure how long it will take for the new domain to start showing up in Google...

Comment: IMPORTANT: I've just corrected a (silly) mistake in the `RewriteRule`. It needs the trailing `/$1` on the end of the substitution! Without this, all URLs would redirect to your homepage (which would still cause Google to pass the 301 redirect initially)! (Sorry about that.)

Comment: Thanks! Have made the change. Was it the right thing to request the change of address/domain from subdomain to new domain on the Google webmaster console?

Comment: Yes, that is a good thing to do.

Comment: Still waiting for Google to index my new domain... I did have 2 unknown folders show up as 404 not found on the new domain. 'm/' and 'mobile/' Neither of these folders are part of my site.  Any ideas why Google is 404ing them? They are not 404 on my x10host domain that links to exactly the same data...

Comment: Google won't index the new domain overnight; "it could take weeks"! Many questions about this already on this site. You say `m/` and `mobile/` are valid URLs on the x10host domain, but 404 on you main domain? Or are you just referring to the report in GWT? If Google tries to crawl a URL that doesn't exist - regardless of how it found that URL - you'll likely get a 404 reported in GWT. There was a question like this asked recently, specifically mentioning the `m/` and `mobile/` folders as I recall.

Comment: Thanks w3d. Yes, the old x10host subdomain... Which has been crawled and indexed for a couple of months has never shown a 404 in GWT on these folders.  It has shown up on the new .com domain in GWT on an early crawl before any html docs have been indexed.  I have read the other question on this forum.  One person indicates it could be if someone previously owned the domain and used those folders. Find that hard to believe as my domain name is quite unique (firstname+surname+music). Unlikely this domain has been used before.